# Matlab - Recursive function to browse and modify a structure

Tags: matlab, recursion, struct

I have some troubles with a Matlab recursive function that I created in order to browse a data structure and modify each field that contains a path starting by a keyword.

My function that replaces a relative path starting by a keyword by an absolute path works perfectly fine and has already been tested (for instance, '$KEYWORD\Desktop\Documents' will be replaced by 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Documents')

I am trying to apply this function to a data structure that contains many (too many) fields, with a recursive function. I want this recursive function to browse my data structure, and as soon as it detects a char parameter starting by *$KEYWORD*, it changes the value by an absolute path stored in an environment parameter. 
Here is my code:

```
function newStruct = browse_struct(initStruct)

   fields = fieldnames(initStruct);
   n_fields = length(fields);

   for n = 1 : n_fields
      val = getfield(initStruct, fields{n});
      if isstruct(val)
         browse_struct(val);
      elseif( ischar(val) && val(1)=='$' )
         newVal = replace_keyword(val);
         newStruct = setfield(initStruct, fields{n}, newVal);
      end
   end

end
```

When I run my code in debug mode, I see that my function browses entirely my data structure, and that the fields of interest are being replaced by what I want, but when the run is over, the new structure is identical to initial one. No field has been changed, so in the end I still have relative paths starting by *$KEYWORD*, while it should be an absolute path instead.

I also tried to replace the line 7 (the one just under the if condition) by:

```
newStruct = browse_struct(val)
```

And it doesn't work either, it completely destroys the initial structure.

I don't know how to fix that problem. Can someone help me please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are dealing with 2 different instances of your `struct`, named `val` and `newstruct`. When your recursive function starts you should assign `newStruct=initStruct;` at the start and then do modifications (if/where necessary) on that `newStruct`, before you return it as output.

Comment: Hi Hoki, thanks for your proposal. I added ```newStruct = initStruct;``` at the begining of the code, but it does not change anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1:** In your function you are applying changes to `newStruct` but keep using `initStruct` for new changes, so you are overriding previous changes to `newStruct`.

**Solution:** when you pass a struct (or any object) to a function in MATLAB, you pass it by value, so the original struct does not change. You can simply remove `newStruct` from the function and only work with `initStruct`.

**Problem 2:** `browse_struct(val);` does not change the struct, and `newStruct = browse_struct(val);` changes the struct to its field.

**Solution:** Use `newStruct = setfield(initStruct, fields{n}, browse_struct(val));`

The corrected function:

```
function initStruct = browse_struct(initStruct)

    fields = fieldnames(initStruct);
    n_fields = length(fields);

    for n = 1 : n_fields
        val = getfield(initStruct, fields{n});
        if isstruct(val)
            initStruct = setfield(initStruct, fields{n}, browse_struct(val));
        elseif( ischar(val) && val(1)=='$' )
            newVal = replace_keyword(val);
            initStruct = setfield(initStruct, fields{n}, newVal);
        end
    end

end
```

Instead of using `getfield` and `setfield`, MATLAB suggests "**Use dynamic field names with structures**" so you can modify the function like this:

```
function initStruct = browse_struct(initStruct)

    fields = fieldnames(initStruct);
    n_fields = length(fields);

    for n = 1 : n_fields
        val = initStruct.(fields{n});
        if isstruct(val)
            initStruct.(fields{n}) = browse_struct(val);
        elseif( ischar(val) && val(1)=='$' )
            newVal = replace_keyword(val);
            initStruct.(fields{n}) = newVal;
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Many thanks Eliahu Aaron. I understand better my mistakes thanks to your great explanations. Now it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Good job explaining the subtleties of recursive functions (coupled with MATLAB passing everything by value). +1 ;)